# probability of at least one ace, not using the complement rule

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

I know to calculate the probability in a 5 card hand of at least one ace, one could calculate the probability of no aces, and take 1 - that. but if i wanted to do it directly without the complement to test my understanding, how would I do this?

The way i see it is this is a union problem, so its one ace, or 2 aces, or 3 aces etc..

so what I came up with is:
$4 \choose 1$$48 \choose 4$ + $4 \choose 2$$48 \choose 3$  + $4 \choose 3$$48 \choose 2$ + $4 \choose 4$$48 \choose 1$

in the numerator (the total number of cards with at least one ace?  and then the denominator is $52 \choose 5$

But This answer is different than what i get with the 1- pr(no ace). so I am wondering where I am going wrong?

Comment: [$1-\dfrac{\binom{4}{0}\binom{48}{5}}{\binom{52}{5}}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+-+%2848+choose+5%29%2F%2852+choose+5%29) $= \dfrac{18472}{54145}=$ [$\dfrac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{48}{4}+\binom{4}{2}\binom{48}{3}+\binom{4}{3}\binom{48}{2}+\binom{4}{4}\binom{48}{1}}{\binom{52}{5}}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%284+choose+1%29%2848+choose+4%29+%2B+%284+choose+2%29%2848+choose+3%29%2B%284+choose+3%29%2848+choose+2%29%2B%284+choose+4%29%2848+choose+1%29%29%2F%2852+choose+5%29).  You must have some arithmetic mistakes.

Comment: How did you calculate it using the complement? Because what you have done for the direct method looks correct to me, resulting in 886,656 hands with at least one ace.

Comment: See [Vandermonde's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)